# Using axes in Matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

My interest is to display image in axes, I've 2 GUI's input_window and fig5.
In my former GUI I've used one axes to display image using `uigetfile` ,

```
axes(handles.axes1);
imshow(fname);
```

Now by pressing `pushbutton` in 1st GUI it switches to fig5 GUI, where I've used so many axes to display multiple images, also i want to display `fname` image in one axes and it should automatically  get displayed in fig5 GUI. For this I've used same above codes in `Fig5_OpeningFcn`

```
axes(handles.axes1);
imshow(fname);
```

I'm getting error like `Undefined function or variable 'fname'`.
please help me how to pass variables between GUI's

Answer (score 0):

You could use `setappdata` and `getappdata`, like so:

```
% In the first figure:
setappdata(0, 'fname', fname);
% Show the second figure...


% In the second figure:
fname = getappdata(0, 'fname');
% Clear the appdata
setappdata(0, 'fname', '');
% Do stuff with fname
```

Comment: Where should i copy `setappdata(0, 'fname', fname);` in my first GUI? i copied in `Input_window_OpeningFcn` and I'm getting error `Undefined function or variable 'fname'`

Comment: i've used `setappdata(Fig5, 'fname', fname);` in `Input_window_OpeningFcn` and `fname = getappdata(Input_window, 'fname');` in `Fig5_OpeningFcn`. I got a new ERROR and I'm not getting why recursion has reached limit, a bit afraid of this error                                                            `Maximum recursion limit of 500 reached. Use set(0,'RecursionLimit',N)
to change the limit.  Be aware that exceeding your available stack space can
crash MATLAB and/or your computer.

Error in ==> isprop`

Comment: This means something is calling itself indefinitely. This could be happening because, e.g., function A is calling function B, and function B is calling A, which calls B, which calls A, etc. Perhaps each UI is trying to open the other?

Comment: Exactly, Then using `setappdata` and `getappdata` how can i pass variable between GUI's? Where should i copy `setappdata(0, 'fname', fname);` in my first GUI?

Comment: Well you need to `setappdata` before you `getappdata`. So `setappdata` at some point before you need the variable in the second GUI (whenever it becomes available) and then `getappdata` afterwards. If both GUIs need the variable as soon as they open, then do your `setappdata` before you open either of them.

Comment: What does `0` represents in `setappdata(0, 'fname', fname);`

Comment: You should read [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/setappdata.html). `0` here means it's the "global" app data.